# svn error when commit directory

Tags: svn

I use svn to commit a folder a checked out before and I get the message "containing working copy admin area is missing"

This is the command I used:

svn commit -m svn: /home/user/workspace/data/xyz

The path /home/user/workspace/data/xyz is on my local pc where xyz is the folder I checked out before.

Comment: It seems the checkout copy is not completed, i.e., have you pressed Ctrl-C in previous `svn checkout` command?

Comment: Why are you passing that argument?  The -m switch is to specify the commit message.  You seem to be using the path as the log message.  If you want to commit the changes to that directory, then you need to run svn commit while in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to check out another working copy, and move your changes to the new copy, but be careful skip the .svn/ files:

```
data$ cp -a xyz xyz.bak
data$ cd xyz
data/xyz$ find -type d -name .svn -prune | xargs rm -fr
data/xyz$ cd ..
data$ mv xyz xyz-broken
data$ svn checkout ... xyz-new
data$ cp -R xyz-broken/* xyz-new/
```

Umm.. I have not tested the script, hope it works!